# How can I edit an existing thematic shapefile composed of contiguous polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, polygon, thematic-map

I cannot edit an existing thematic shapefile layer composed entirely of contiguous polygons. I created the layer many years ago using ArcGIS Desktop; the themes represent the depth of water in a shallow harbour https://www.wexfordharbour.info/iChart. My license for ArcGIS has expired and I cannot afford the €200 for a home license so I decided to try QGis. At first sight it seemed perfect. I opened a project and imported the shapefile. I imported a satellite map, georeferenced it and now I want to modify the polygons according to the underlying sandbanks and shallows showing on the satellite image.

I spent a while removing all geometry errors; they were minor and mostly around the outer box surrounding the shapefile. Now I want to edit polygons to change their shape. QGis Reshape Features does not work for me, nothing happens. Creating a polygon totally within an existing one (Fill Ring) works fine but if and of the surrounding polygon is included, even one vertex, the create does not complete giving a warning "Could not create ring since the inserted Ring crosses existing rings".

If I create polygons using Add Polygon, the result is empty and I cannot select it using Identify Features button. Though the outline is apparent it appears to be a polyline rather than a polygon.

Finally, I cannot clip the underlying layer with a newly created Part of Polygon using a button or even the Plugin Vector/Clipper/Clip. It just gives a host of errors.

If I empty the whole shapefile and digitise Polygons and Rings where I want them all seems fine except that I cannot create a Ring within a Ring if it shares any of the boundary.

I have 30 years of experience with ArcInfo/ArcView/ArcGIS so I do know the concepts of GIS but I am stumped. How can I do those?

Comment: Please try the "vertice tool" and check your snapping tool settings.

Comment: Thanks Erik, I do find Vertex tool very useful for deleting vertices while retaining the geometry within the polygon and also, to clean up slivers etc. I haven't been successful using Vertex Tool with editing; if I move a vertex inside a polygon it leaves empty space. If I move a vertex outside its polygon I get a triangular area with double identity. If I click inside the new area with the Identity Tool it selects that polygon and the surrounding polygon. In any case, all the polygons in my shapefile have hundreds of vertices.